# Aurelia asking for strange ...xxxHTMLLINKxxx... file that is never there

Tags: aurelia, webpack-file-loader

My Aurelia app (which I took over from another programmer) keeps requesting a file:
xxxHTMLLINKxxx0.241767597227476870.4882104576985471xxx
and I can't find where it is coming from or how to stop it.

Anyone?

Comment: You aren't going to get an answer with a vague question like this. You need to provide more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see it mentioned here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader/issues/93

In one of the comments: "it's just a placeholder which webpack replaces with a Url Request"

It points to the webpack contributed module "Html-loader", which is rewritten in 1.0.0-alpha. It also mentions a breaking change in the needed minimal versions for Webpack and node.

So please check these versions.